Find the exact value of $\DeclareMathOperator{\cosec}{cosec} \cosec(10^\circ) + \cosec(50^\circ) - \cosec(70^\circ)$

Find the exact value of $\cosec(10^\circ) + \cosec(50^\circ) - \cosec(70^\circ)$.

The equation can be written as
$$
\cosec(x) + \cosec(60^\circ-x) - \cosec(60^\circ+x),
$$
where $x = 10^\circ$.
I also know that
$$
\sin(x) + \sin(60^\circ-x) + \sin(60^\circ+x) = \frac{\sin(3x)}{4}.
$$
This equation and identity have the same format, so I got the idea to use it.
Can I use this information to find the answer?
(This question is from a book called Advanced Problems in JEE, in case someone wants to know about it.)

This appears to be a duplicate of one of my old questions here.

Though you accepted one, the 4 answers below do not answer your precise question: 'This equation and identity have the same format, so I got the idea to use it. (And of course, neither do the answers in the old post.)

I don't offhand know how to use your equation involving $\sin$. Instead, we have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \cosec(10^\circ) + \cosec(50^\circ) - \cosec(70^\circ) \\
& = \frac{1}{\sin(10^\circ)} + \frac{1}{\sin(50^\circ)} - \frac{1}{\sin(70^\circ)} \\
& = \frac{\sin(70^\circ)\sin(50^\circ) + \sin(70^\circ)\sin(10^\circ) - \sin(50^\circ)\sin(10^\circ)}{\sin(10^\circ)\sin(50^\circ)\sin(70^\circ)}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
As shown in multiple answers in Find the numerical value of $\sin 10^\circ \sin 50^\circ \sin 70^\circ$. (e.g., this one), with the denominator, we get
$$\sin(10^\circ)\sin(50^\circ)\sin(70^\circ) = \frac{1}{8} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
The Product-to-sum identities section of Wikipedia's "List of Trigonometric Identities" article has
$$\sin \theta \,\sin \varphi ={\cos(\theta -\varphi )-\cos(\theta +\varphi ) \over 2} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
Thus, the numerator of \eqref{eq1A} becomes
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& \frac{(\cos(20^{\circ}) - \cos(120^{\circ})) + (\cos(60^{\circ}) - \cos(80^{\circ})) - (\cos(40^{\circ}) - \cos(60^{\circ}))}{2} \\
& = \frac{(\cos(20^{\circ}) + \frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{2} - \cos(80^{\circ})) - (\cos(40^{\circ}) - \frac{1}{2})}{2} \\
& = \frac{\frac{3}{2} + \cos(20^{\circ}) - \cos(80^{\circ}) - \cos(40^{\circ})}{2}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
From this Math SE answer, using the expansion of $\cos(80^{\circ}) = \cos(60^{\circ} + 20^{\circ})$ and $\cos(40^{\circ}) = \cos(60^{\circ} - 20^{\circ})$, we get $\cos(20^\circ) = \cos(80^\circ) + \cos(40^\circ) \;\to\; \cos(20^\circ) - \cos(80^\circ) - \cos(40^\circ) = 0$. Thus, \eqref{eq4A} simplifies to $\frac{3}{4}$. Using this and \eqref{eq2A} in \eqref{eq1A}, we end up with
$$\cosec(10^\circ) + \cosec(50^\circ) - \cosec(70^\circ) = \frac{\frac{3}{4}}{\frac{1}{8}} = 6 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Rewrite the first term using the triple angle identity with $x=30^\circ$:
$$\sin x = 3 \sin \frac x3 - 4 \sin^3 \frac x3$$

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12 &= 3\sin10^\circ - 4\sin^310^\circ \tag{$*$} \\ \implies \csc 10^\circ &= 6 - 8\sin^2 10^\circ
\end{align*}$$

Join the other terms with the sum identity,
$$\sin(x\pm y) = \sin x\cos y \pm \cos x \sin y$$

$$\begin{align*}
\sin (60^\circ\pm t) &= \frac{\sqrt3}2 \cos t \pm \frac12 \sin t \\
\stackrel{t=10^\circ}\implies \csc 50^\circ - \csc 70^\circ &= \frac2{\sqrt3\cos10^\circ-\sin10^\circ} - \frac2{\sqrt3\cos10^\circ+\sin10^\circ} \\
&= \frac{4\sin10^\circ}{3\cos^210^\circ - \sin^210^\circ} \\
&= \frac{4\sin10^\circ}{3 - 4\sin^2 10^\circ}
\end{align*}$$

By $(*)$, we end up with
$$\begin{align*}
& 6 - 8\sin^2 10^\circ + \frac{4\sin10^\circ}{3-4\sin^210^\circ} \\
&= 6 + \frac{4\sin10^\circ - 24\sin^210^\circ + 32\sin^410^\circ}{3-4\sin^210^\circ} \\
&= \boxed{6} + \frac{4\sin10^\circ}{3-4\sin^210^\circ} \underbrace{\left(1 - 6\sin10^\circ + 8\sin^3 10^\circ\right)}_{=0}
\end{align*}$$

@Mike That should do it. I appreciate the feedback :)

Since you received good answers, a $1,400^+$ years old approximate answer
$$A=\csc (x)+\csc \left(\frac{\pi}{3}-x\right)-\csc \left(\frac{\pi}{3}+x\right)=\frac{3 \csc (x)}{2 \cos (2 x)+1}$$
For $x=\frac \pi {18}$, $\sin(x)\sim \frac{17}{97}$, $\cos(2x)\sim  \frac{77}{82}$
$$A\sim \frac{11931}{2006}=6-\frac{105}{2006}$$ (relative error of $0.87$%)
